# Create a triangle with just one print function

Tags: python, printing

There are some restrictions:

1. You can not just build the whole triangle with string then print.
2. Code must be using loops.

The output I want to create:

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 
1 2 
1
```

This was our exam question but I couldn't find the solution after hours of thinking.

Comment: Build a string containing the whole triangle and print it.

Comment: Basically what @Norrius said. There must have been more restrictions than that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version with parameters:

```
print '\n'.join(' '.join(str(j + 1) for j in range(5 - abs(i))) for i in range(-5, 6))
```

or in Python 3:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(j + 1) for j in range(5 - abs(i))) for i in range(-5, 6)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily by using the "\n" for line breaks:

```
print "1\n1 2\n1 2 3\n1 2 3 4\n1 2 3 4 5\n1 2 3 4\n1 2 3\n1 2\n1"
```

..or in 3.x

```
print("1\n1 2\n1 2 3\n1 2 3 4\n1 2 3 4 5\n1 2 3 4\n1 2 3\n1 2\n1")
```

Comment: I'd use a multi-line string literal. Much prettier.